# Using a VPN with a windows virtual machine (VirtualBox) anonymous enough?

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, anonymity

I want to be anonymous enough not to get my host machine hacked/attacked or my real IP address exposed.

So, is using a VPN inside a Windows virtual machine using Oracle VirtualBox enough?

Should I also use a VPN on my host PC too?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this article on [what topics are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: VPN does little for being " hacked/attacked", you still have an IP address. VPN also doesn't do all that much for anonymity, it just give you a _different_ IP address than your ISP. Use a firewall for protecting your network. Use Tor for anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a good VPN provider. If you want to use free vpn, just let it be. It won't help you in any way.

You can cascade by using VPN on your host and also on your VM, otherwise it is possible to get your real IP address.

Just check your settings with pages like ip-check.info or ip-score.com.